# Mysql select query with multiple dynamic conditions

Tags: python, mysql

Suppose I have the table:

```
** Table**
---------------------------------------
ID  Type    Number  Size    Location
---------------------------------------
1   Apple   5       M        A
2   Apple   4       S        B
3   Banana  5       M        B
4   Apple   7       S        A
5   Pear    5       L        C
6   Pear    5       M        A
7   Apple   3       L        A
8   Pear    2       M        A
9   Banana  4       M        B
```

my program is select.py [-t type] [-n number] [-s size] [-l location]
(all parameters are optional.)

if -t is given, then it will run "select * from table where Type= args.type";

if -n is given, then it will run "select * from table where Number= args.number";

if both -t and -n are given, then it will run "select * from table where Type= 
args.type and Number = args.number";

...

if all parameters are given, then it will run "select * from table where Type= args.type and Number = args.number and ... and ..";

How can I write a common where clause to cover all above possible cases?

Comment: Please edit your question, so it would be more readable for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using an ORM or not, but you can construct a native MySQL query with the logic as shown below. The idea is that the first parameter of each [IFNULL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) i.e. the NULL values, are to be the variables of the query in your program. This way if the value is null then we compare the data in that column of the turple with itself so that the condition returns true.

```
-- IF AT LEAST ONE PARAMETER PASSED
SELECT A.*
FROM TEST A
WHERE 
        A.ID=IFNULL(NULL,A.ID) 
    AND A.TYPE=IFNULL('Pear',A.TYPE)
    AND A.NUMBER=IFNULL(NULL,A.NUMBER)
    AND A.SIZE=IFNULL('L',A.SIZE)
    AND A.LOCATION=IFNULL(NULL,A.LOCATION);

-- NO PARAMETER PASSED
SELECT A.*
FROM TEST A
WHERE 
        A.ID=IFNULL(NULL,A.ID) 
    AND A.TYPE=IFNULL(NULL,A.TYPE)
    AND A.NUMBER=IFNULL(NULL,A.NUMBER)
    AND A.SIZE=IFNULL(NULL,A.SIZE)
    AND A.LOCATION=IFNULL(NULL,A.LOCATION);
```

See a working demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba30cd/9)